# Solving Autoload javascript Menu

Tags: javascript, menu, accordion

Heelo everyone, i never worked with javascript before, and i'm developing an accordion menu.
It's working fine when i use the function click. but when i try to load a page with an li a with the class="active", the function above doesn't work. Am i using the ready function uncorretly?

Hope for some help. Thanks!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
          $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
          $(this).next().slideToggle();
          $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
        }
      });
      $('#nav > li > a').ready(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'active'){
            $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
          $(this).next().slideToggle();

        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#nav > li').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('a').hasClass('active')){
        $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
    }
});
```

or

```
$('#nav > li > a').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).parent().find('ul').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Instead of this

```
$('#nav > li > a').ready(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'active'){
        //your code here
    }
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XumC/)

Comment: Just added a fiddle. It's used inside the doc ready. Let me know if it works

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7XumC/1/

Here's an update! This is all the behaviors, but like you see i tell to slideDown only the active class "li" but both of them opens!

Comment: ahh ha... I understand now! I have modified the fiddle. lemme know if it works http://jsfiddle.net/7XumC/2/